# Laravel FB SDK v4 requesting w. recursion

Tags: php, laravel, queue, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am currently working with laravel and the php fb sdk v4 to gather posts from a page after having a user signup. Here is the flow of what I am attempting.

1. push a job onto the queue.
2. In that job request from fb the first 25 posts via a call similar to this...

   ```
       $session = new FacebookSession($session);
       $request = new FacebookRequest(
               $session,
               'GET',
               '/PAGEIDHERE/postsfields=id,created_time,picture&limit=25'
           );

       $response = $request->execute();
       $responseData = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
   ```
3. Save that data and get the next page via pagination

   ```
    $request = $response->getRequestForNextPage();
    $parameters = $request->getParameters();
   ```
4. kill the current job

   ```
   $job->delete();
   ```
5. Push a new job onto the queue

   ```
   Queue::push("CLASS", ['parameters' => $parameters]);
   ```
6. Run the same class again but with the parameters filled in for the request. The parameters are essentially the same as what is called in the inital request however it includes a token for the next page. What Im struggling with is how to populate the facebookrequest object. The queuing in laravel serializes all data when it passes it to the the class so I am unable to simply pass the next page data as it is. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple solve, my first attempt at this must have thrown errors for other reasons. Just make the request with those parameters appended.

```
           $request = new FacebookRequest(
                $session,
                'GET',
                $endpoint,
                $parameters
            );
```